# Wait for invoked method to finish?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have something like a demon function, it's started on new thread, and it is an endless loop that checks for condition, if true it updates textbox, it sleaps some time, and so, again and again. The function I use to update the textbox is this:

```
private static void pour(TextBox t, string s)
    {
        try
        {
            Form f = t.FindForm();
            if (t.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(pour);
                f.Invoke(d, new object[] { t, s });
            }
            else
            {
                if (t.Text == "") t.Text += s;
                else t.Text += Environment.NewLine + s;
                if (t.Text != "") { t.Select(t.Text.Count() - 2, 1); t.ScrollToCaret(); }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The problem is, the demon will invoke pour on the main thread and continue before the textbox is updated, thus invoking pour few times, that results in the textbox being updated few times with the same text, instead of once. How to wait for this invoked method to finish?

edit:
This is the demon function:

```
private void demon_drain(string name, int interval)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread drain = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TextBox t = new TextBox();
                        try
                        {
                            t = (TextBox)F.Controls[name];
                        }
                        catch { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval); continue; }
                        if (Drain == null) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval); continue; }
                        if (Drain == t.Text) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval); continue; }
                        pour(t, Drain);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval); continue;
                    }
                    catch { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval); continue; }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        });
        drain.IsBackground = true;
        drain.Start();
    }
```

When I set a break point after the pour it works fine, and the shorter the sleep, the more updates are done, thus I think it's not waiting for the invoke, actually...

Comment: Invoke does wait to finish. The reason for the problem is something else.

Comment: Are there exceptions? You probably put in the catch blocks for a reason.

Comment: Calling demon_drain() more than once is an obvious possible reason.  Add tracing.

Comment: No, I call it just once, in it's class constructor, that is called just once on main formload, I'm absolutley sure it is called just once. And the catch blocks are there because the demon is working from the application start, "forever", and the textbox is dynamically added and removed on some user action, so if there's no textbox it just continues until there is, it is not that I've putted it because of some errors or issues...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how to include a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example in your post. In the meantime, there are some obvious problems in your code unrelated to the question: 1) don't initialize `t`; it will be initialized by the next statement and it's a waste to create a new `TextBox` you're always just going to throw away; 2) don't have a blanket `catch`; even better, don't use exception handling for flow control at all, just check the `Controls` collection (e.g. if it's a dictionary, use `TryGetValue()`);

Comment: (continued...) 3) don't waste time getting the `Form` instance (i.e. `FindForm()`); the `t` object passed to the method has a perfectly good `Invoke()` method you can use; 4) if the existing text is empty, don't waste time concatenating new text to the empty string, just assign the new text to the `Text` property.

Comment: If this is (close to) your real code then replace the whole mess with a Forms.Timer. There is so much wrong here. As a hint: real code shouldn't Sleep(). A while-loop shouldn't have so much `continue`s and catch blocks shouldn't be empty.